# Comparing consecutive rows within an file

Tags: unix, awk

I have two files with with 1s and 0s in each column, where the field separator is "," :

```
1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0
0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0
1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0
1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1
1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
```

Want I want to do is look at the file in pairs of rows, compare them, and if they are exactly the same output a 1. So for this example the rows 1 & 2 are different so they don't get a 1, rows 3 & 4 are exactly the same so they get a 1, and rows 5&6 differ by 1 column so they don't get a 1, and so on.

So the desired output could be something like :

```
1
1
1
```

Because here there are exactly 3 pairs (they are paired by the fact if they are consecutive) of rows that are exactly the same: rows 3&4, 7&8, and 9&10. The comparison should not reuse a row, so if you compare rows 1 & 2, you shouldn't then compare rows 2 & 3.

Comment: Giving some programming language preference (awk, perl, js+node.js) might help potential answerers - it should be quite easy thing to answer

Comment: What have you tried, where have you failed and what problem did you encounter ?

Comment: What language do you want to use?  The question is tagged Unix, so do you want to use Shell script?  Python would be one of the easiest options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with awk like:

```
awk -F, '!(NR%2) {print $0==p} {p=$0}' data
0
1
0
1
1
```

where every line that's evenly divisible by two will print a `0` if the current line doesn't match the last value for `p` or a `1` if it matches.

If you truly only want the `1`s, which is throwing away any information about which pairs matched, you could:

```
awk -F, '!(NR%2)&&$0==p {print 1} {p=$0}' data
1
1
1
```

Alternatively, you could output matching pair line numbers like:

```
awk -F, '!(NR%2)&&$0==p {print NR-1 "," NR} {p=$0}' data
3,4
7,8
9,10
```

Or just the counts of all matched pairs:

```
awk -F, '!(NR%2)&&$0==p {c++} {p=$0} END{ print c}' data
3
```

Another useful variant might be just to return the matching lines directly:

```
awk -F, '!(NR%2)&&$0==p {print} {p=$0}' data
1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a shell script like this:

```
while read line
do
    if test "$prevline" = "$line"
    then
        echo 1
    fi      

    prevline=$line
done
```

I'm not 100% sure about your requirement to "not reuse a row", but I think that could be achieved by changing inner part of the loop to

```
    if test "$prevline" = "$line"
    then
        echo 1
        line=""        # don't reuse a line
    fi
```